# Return the whole file with AJAX/JSON

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I have one file with a long script which has a variable "period" in it. I will send the value of that variable via the front page of the site to that file. The value will be filled into the file and return it to the front page.
So I want the code `<code period="x">` placed in the front page as something like `<code period="1">`

I want to do that multiple times with different values.
Does someone know how this can be done?

I saw this script, but it didn't work:

```
if($error === false) {
alert($error);
$.ajax({
    url: '\get.php',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: "json",
    data: {
        period: "1"
    },
    success: function(data){
        alert(JSON.stringify(data));
    }
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You have a syntax error. See the inline comment:

```
if($error === false) {
    alert($error);
    $.ajax({
        url: '/get.php',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
            period: "1"
        },
        success: function(data){
            alert(JSON.stringify(data));
        }
    });
} // << this was missing
```

Comment: @Ahmed Do you see any errors in the browser console?

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input index.php:74

Comment: @Ahmed That means you have a syntax error on the server side. Your JavaScript problem is fixed now. You can ask a new question for that.

Answer (score 1):

you missed a } for the callback to success.

Answer (score 1):

```
if($error === false) {
alert($error);
$.ajax({
    url: '/get.php',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: "json",
    data: {
        period: "1"
    },
    success: function(data){
        alert(JSON.stringify(data));
    } 
});
}// **This was missing**
```

Comment: Thank you, but it still shows nothing. It does say: $error not defined and when I remove the error piece and only leave the ajax piece it gives no errors, but it also doesn't show anything